# Given first chrono time, calculate value of next results given the gaps

Tags: java, time

I have some sports time results returned by an xml feed.

Result time for the first arrived is returned and converted like this:

```
String time = "00:01:00:440";
String gap = "";
```

for the other partecipants I get back only the gap:

```
String time = "";
String gap = "00:00:00:900";
```

How can I calculate the time of others partecipants given the gap from the first?

I have tried with java `Date` object but it uses calendar days too and I get strange result:

```
String firstTime = "00:01:00:440";
String gapOne = "00:00:00:900";

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss:SSS");

Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;
long diff = 0;
String timeResult = "";

try {

    d1 = formatter.parse(firstTime);
    d2 = formatter.parse(gapOne);
    diff = d2.getTime() + d1.getTime();
    timeResult = formatter.format(new Date(diff));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(timeResult);
```

But prints out:

```
11:01:01:340
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
String firstTime = "00:01:00:440";
String gapOne = "00:00:00:900";

String firstTimeSplit[] = firstTime.split(":");
String gapSplit[] = gapOne.split(":");

int millisecSum = Integer.parseInt(firstTimeSplit[3]) + Integer.parseInt(gapSplit[3]);
int secsSum = Integer.parseInt(firstTimeSplit[2]) + Integer.parseInt(gapSplit[2]);
int minSum = Integer.parseInt(firstTimeSplit[1]) + Integer.parseInt(gapSplit[1]);
int hrsSum = Integer.parseInt(firstTimeSplit[0]) + Integer.parseInt(gapSplit[0]);

String millisec = String.format("%03d", millisecSum % 1000);

int mathSec = millisecSum / 1000 + secsSum;
String secs = String.format("%02d", mathSec % 60);

int mathMins = mathSec / 60 + minSum;
String mins = String.format("%02d", mathMins % 60);

int mathHrs = mathMins / 60 + hrsSum;
String hrs = String.format("%02d", mathHrs % 60);

String format = "%s:%s:%s:%s";
String result = String.format(format, hrs, mins, secs, millisec);
```

This way I get returned the value this way:

```
00:01:01:340
```